# Support for Flink ACL in YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

In a secured Hadoop cluster I am trying to access Flink AM page and logs from YARN and seeing the following error:
`User %remoteUser  are not authorized to view application %appID`

Seems like that the cause is lack of support of ACL in YARN from Flink side.

**How the code works**

The message comes from hadoop/yarn/server/AppBlock class which uses ApplicationACLsManager class. This class performs checks and refers to app info which was set in RMAppManager:

`this.applicationACLsManager.addApplication(applicationId,
        submissionContext.getAMContainerSpec().getApplicationACLs()`

AMContainerSpec is ContainerLaunchContext class which has a PB implementation, submitted from the framework side.

From Flink, this object is created in AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor class which (and other classes in Flink) doesn't call setApplicationACLs.

**Question**

Is there a way to bypass this or the right solution is to contribute the support to Flink? What is the state of this feature from the Flink side?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a limitation in Flink which we should fix. Please open a JIRA issue. The community would be very happy if you could help implementing it.